# Playing an audio file with ExoPlayer a few seconds after calling .prepare()

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I have a feature in my app that has to play one short audio file multiple times, and using the code below I'm preparing `ExoPlayer` to play the audio:

```
SimpleExoPlayer player;
private void readyExoPlayerRaw(int rawSound) {
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());
    DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(rawSound));
    final RawResourceDataSource rawResourceDataSource = new RawResourceDataSource(this);
    try {
        rawResourceDataSource.open(dataSpec);
    } catch (RawResourceDataSource.RawResourceDataSourceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaSource audioSource = 
        new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "appName"))
            .createMediaSource(rawResourceDataSource.getUri());

    player.prepare(audioSource);
    //player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

The problem is that the sound plays fine when I uncomment the last line (`//player.setPlayWhenReady(true);`), but since I'm playing the sound a few seconds after I run this method, this line of code wont work! I think because it waits for a callback from previous line (`.prepare(...)`) and when it's ready, it will then play. So I thought that maybe I should call `start()` or something like that on the player, but there's just no such method.

So I'm stuck with calling `.prepare()` each time I want to play the audio, but since it plays in very short intervals, calling `prepare()` causes an unsuitable delay.

So am I missing something? How can I play a prepared `MediaSource` without preparing it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track!

`setPlayWhenReady` is how you pause and play the audio, but it'll only actually play when it's "ready" aka done preparing.

So you should only have to call your `readyExoPlayerRaw` once probably in onResume or onCreate. Then at the end of that method you can set `playWhenReady(false)` so that it doesn't start playing until you tell it to.

Then when you want to play the sound, do something like the following:

```
private void playSound() {
    // Go to the beginning of the audio (in case it has played before)
    player.seekTo(0);
    // Tell it to play the sound
    exoPlayer. setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Let me know if that works.